# Spring Aspectj @Before all rest method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, aop, aspectj

Before spring introduce `@GetMapping`, there only one annotation we care about `@RequestMapping`, so, this aspect works

```
@Before("within(aa.bb.*.rest..*) && execution(public * *(..)) && @within(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController) && @annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)")
```

But after we can use `@GetMapping`, `@PostMapping`, this point not works, but these annotations have a meta annotation `@RequestMapping`.

Is there any way to easily intercept all `@RequestMapping`/`@{Get,Post,Put,Patch,..}Mapping` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found this syntax [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38209801/1870054) works for me!

```
@Pointcut("execution(@(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping *) * *(..))")
public void requestMappingAnnotations() { }
```

Also I can list them all

```
@Pointcut("within(aa.bb.*.rest..*)  && @within(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController)")
public void restControllers() {}

@Pointcut("@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping) " +
    "|| @annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping)" +
    "|| @annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping)" +
    "|| @annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PatchMapping)" +
    "|| @annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping)" +
    "|| @annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping)"
)
public void mappingAnnotations() {}

@Pointcut("execution(@(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping *) * *(..))")
public void requestMappingAnnotations() { }

@Before("restControllers() && requestMappingAnnotations()")
public void onExecute(JoinPoint jp) {}
```