# Spring AOP - get value from GetMapping

Tags: spring-aop

I remove @RequestMapping from my controller and now I´m using @GetMapping. I want to get values from GetMapping object to log on my aspect

Based on [Spring Aspectj @Before all rest method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42642681/spring-aspectj-before-all-rest-method)

I tried:

```
@Pointcut("execution(@(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping *) * *(..))")
public void controller(RequestMapping requestMapping) {}
```

Also:

```
@Pointcut("execution(@(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping *) * *(..))")
    public void controller(GetMapping getMapping) {}
```

Also:

```
@Pointcut("@annotation(getMapping)")
    public void controller(GetMapping getMapping) {
    }
```

I´m always receiving this error: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut

My initial configuration was:

```
@Pointcut("@annotation(requestMapping)")
    public void controller(RequestMapping requestMapping) {
    }
```

Comment: I got the same problem when I remove @RequestMapping from my Controller, AOP work for @ PostMapping but not for @ GetMapping