# Spring AOP: is there a way to make @target work for indirect annotations?

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I have an annotation:

```
@Inherited
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
public @interface MyAnnotation {
}
```

I annotate Spring MVC controllers with it:

```
@MyAnnotation
public class TestController { ... }
```

Then I add an advice which has the following:

```
@Pointcut("@target(MyAnnotation)")
public void annotatedWithMyAnnotation() {}

@Around("annotatedWithMyAnnotation()")
public Object executeController(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable { ... }
```

Advice's method is invoked successfully.

Now I have a bunch of controllers sharing the same annotations and I want to use a stereotype annotation to group them.

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@MyAnnotation
... other annotations
public @interface StereotypeAnnotation {
}
```

And then I annotate my controllers with `@StereotypeAnnotation`:

```
@StereotypeAnnotation
public class TestController { ... }
```

Controllers do not contain `@MyAnnotation` directly anymore.

**The problem** is that in such a case `@target` pointcut stops matching my controllers, and they are not advised.

Is there a way to define a pointcut that would match controllers having such indirect annotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recreated the situation with pure AspectJ because I do not like Spring AOP so much. This is why I added an extra `execution(* *(..)) &&` in front of the advice's pointcut in order to avoid matching other joinpoints unavailable in Spring AOP, such as `call()`. You can remove it in Spring AOP if you like.

Okay, let's create this situation as you described it:

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Inherited
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE })
public @interface MyAnnotation {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@MyAnnotation
public @interface StereotypeAnnotation {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

@MyAnnotation
public class TestController {
  public void doSomething() {
    System.out.println("Doing something");
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

@StereotypeAnnotation
public class AnotherController {
  public void doSomething() {
    System.out.println("Doing yet another something");
  }
}
```

This is our pure Java driver application (no Spring):

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestController().doSomething();
    new AnotherController().doSomething();
  }
}
```

And this is the aspect:

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class MetaAnnotationAspect {
  @Pointcut(
    "@target(de.scrum_master.app.MyAnnotation) || " +
    "@target(de.scrum_master.app.StereotypeAnnotation)"
  )
  public void solutionA() {}

  @Around("execution(* *(..)) && solutionA()")
  public Object executeController(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(point);
    return point.proceed();
  }
}
```

The log output would be:

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.TestController.doSomething())
Doing something
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.AnotherController.doSomething())
Doing yet another something
```

So far, so good. But what if we add another level of nesting?

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@StereotypeAnnotation
public @interface SubStereotypeAnnotation {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

@SubStereotypeAnnotation
public class YetAnotherController {
  public void doSomething() {
    System.out.println("Doing another something");
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestController().doSomething();
    new AnotherController().doSomething();
    new YetAnotherController().doSomething();
  }
}
```

Then the pointcut would not match the nested meta/stereotype annotation anymore:

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.TestController.doSomething())
Doing something
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.AnotherController.doSomething())
Doing yet another something
Doing another something
```

We would have to explicitly add `|| @target(de.scrum_master.app.StereotypeAnnotation)` to the pointcut, i.e. we would have to know all annotation class names in the hierarchy. There is a way to overcome this using a special syntax for the `within()` pointcut designator, see also [my other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31464543/1082681):

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class MetaAnnotationAspect {
  @Pointcut(
    "within(@de.scrum_master.app.MyAnnotation *) || " +
    "within(@(@de.scrum_master.app.MyAnnotation *) *) || " +
    "within(@(@(@de.scrum_master.app.MyAnnotation *) *) *)"
  )
  public void solutionB() {}

  @Around("execution(* *(..)) && solutionB()")
  public Object executeController(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(point);
    return point.proceed();
  }
}
```

The console log changes to:

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.TestController.doSomething())
Doing something
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.AnotherController.doSomething())
Doing yet another something
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.YetAnotherController.doSomething())
Doing another something
```

See? We only need to know one annotation class, namely `MyAnnotation`, in order to cover two nesting levels of meta annotations. Adding more levels would be straightforward. I admit that this kind of annotation nesting seems pretty much contrived, I just wanted to explain to you which options you have.

Comment: Thank you so much!