# AspectJ: define point-cut for an annotation and all its subtypes (sub-annotations)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, aspectj, spring-aop

I want to put an aspect for any invocation on my end-points in Spring,

I know I can do this with:

```
@Around("@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping) || 
         @annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping) ||
         ....")
```

But since all of them inherit from @RequestMapping annotation, is there a way to indicate something like this:

```
@Around("@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping))
```

And that it matches all the inheritors of @RequestMapping? (@GetMapping, @PutMapping, etc)

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps this other post might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53873984/get-parameters-of-different-annotations-in-a-single-pointcut

Comment: FYI, I closed the question as a duplicate, your question is about how to intercept meta annotations. We are not talking about "subtypes" here, but about annotation like `GetMapping` being decorated by a meta annotation like `RequestMapping`. My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53892842/1082681) to the question @DieterBlancke linked also covers this question, but answers a more complex one with additional requirements.